# Write $\int_1^e \frac{(\ln(\ln(x)))^3}{x}\,dx$ in terms of Gamma function.

Tags: analysis

Write $$\int_1^e \dfrac{(\ln(\ln(x)))^3}{x}\,dx$$ in terms of Gamma function.

I have tried $y=\ln(x)$ but not going to work.

I have tried to substitute $x=e^{e^y}$

but stuck, can you  give me good substitution? How to solve it?

Comment: I don't think you need to use Gamma functions to evaluate this integral. Just use the substitution $y=\ln(x)$ as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you substitute $x=e^{e^y}$ your integral becomes

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \dfrac{y^3}{e^{e^y}}\cdot e^{e^y}\cdot e^y\ dy = \int_{-\infty}^0 y^3 e^y dy$$

or with $z=-y$ and simplifying/switching limits

$$-\int_{0}^\infty (-z)^3 e^{-z} (-dz) = -\int_{0}^\infty z^3 e^{-z} dz = -\Gamma(4) $$

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $y = \ln x$ works perfectly, no?
\begin{align*}
\int_1^e \frac{(\ln \ln x)^3}{x} dx = \int_0^1 (\ln y)^3 dy = \bigg[y(\ln^3(y) - 3\ln^2(y) + 6\ln(y) - 6)\bigg] \Bigg|_0^1 = -6
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{e} \frac{(\ln \ln x)^3}{x} dx$$ Let $\ln x=t$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \ln^3 t dt$$ Integrate it by parts taking $\ln^3 t$ as first function and 1 as second, sucessively, then
$$I=\ln^3t ~t|_{0}^{1}-\int 3\ln^2 t (1/t)t dt= -3 \int \ln^2 t dt$$ $$=-3[\ln^2 t|_{0}^{1} -\int_{0}^{1} 2 \ln t (1/t) t dt]=6\int_{0}^{1} \ln t dt=6(t\ln t-t)|_{0}^{1}=-6.$$